# War file, build by Gradle, do not find resource with withspace

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, gradle, vaadin

I am unsure where my problem exactly is...it shows as following:

- Build my project using Maven, everything works
- Build my project using Gradle, start up and behavior are fine; except for one icon that has a white space in his name

  - If I open the URL I get a 404
  - In my log file I get:

    ```
    2016-02-02 16:55:49 INFO  VaadinServlet:738 - Requested resource [/VAADIN/themes/ThemeName/icon/ic-A A_active.png] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
    ```
  - If I look into the folder in webapps on the server, the file is there. With exactly the same size as in the folder of the maven build.

I use pretty basic stuff and the examples provided by spring boot (for gradle & maven)...

The only difference between maven & gradle that I could spot was that gradle do not have the transform steps of the parent-pom of spring-boot.
Is that the reason? Because spring boot is configuring the war file slightly differently so that white spaces are okay?

Anybody an idea how I can allow white spaces in the war file?

I hope you can understand my questions. I can upload my build files, but they are pretty standard in this regards...

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was based on missing BOMs in gradle.

I skipped the VAADIN BOM but it was updating the version of some VAADIN dependencies...